# How do I uninstall software that was installed with Wine?

Tags: command-line, wine, delete, chown

I am a newbie in Linux and I have a problem uninstalling applications.

I ran this command in console: `sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.wine`, and after that I saw many programs, which I have not installed.

[Here is a screenshot of my applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFLa4.jpg) with the problematic applications circled.

I don't completely understand how I can delete them.

(Moreover, I can't find them in `/usr/share/applications/`)

How can I remove these applications?

Comment: Applications within wine will not be viewable/seen by the native Ubuntu system unless the script/package installed them created links or desktop files that make them visible. Many `wine` applications will only be viewable & executable from within `wine` itself.  I'm no expert on `wine` sorry so can only given this generic comment.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.wine`  Why?! "Moreover, I can't find them in /usr/share/applications/" why do you expect windows software there and not in the C: directory in the .wine directory? "which I have not installed"  yes you have. Those are icons related to you installing wine. Deleting those will also delete wine so I doubt you want that. I would advice to also install Play On Linux package as that installs a lot of scripts to make it easier to use wine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing a couple of things.

~/.local/share/applications/ and /usr/share/applications/ do not contain applications but desktop files. Summarizing a little bit these files tells Gnome where the app is installed, the name and the icon to show. Removing a desktop file only stops Gnome from showing the app but it still installed (is like remove a desktop shortcut on windows)

To remove Ubuntu apps you need to use "sudo apt remove PROGRAM_NAME" or use the graphic Ubuntu shop.

Windows app that you install using Wine are installed on "~/.wine" but the right way to remove then is by typing:

```
wine uninstaller
```

On the other hand I would say that part of the apps that you are showing came by default with wine, hence cannot be uninstalled. You can try to see if their desktop file is under ~/.local/share/applications and remove it to hide them but you cannot uninstall them without remove wine....